# Fixed space between two TextFormField on Flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I'm trying to create an app for my work with login and signup form.

The page is ok, but there is a litte problem: on each TextFormField there is a validator for check the field, but when appears the error message below the field, the other fields goes down.

The question is: how can I fix the textfields?

This is a gif demostration: https://ibb.co/VwNn2f0

I try to use padding or other method finded here or on google, but I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could wrap your `TextField` with a `SizedBox` and set a height for it :

```
SizedBox(
  height: 80,
  child: TextFormField(
    validator: myValidator,
  ),
),
```

or you can also set a style for the error text, with a 0 height :

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorStyle: TextStyle(height: 0),
  ),
);
```

Comment: SizedBox is perfect in this way, that's what i need. Thank you so much
I used only for space between objects eheh